# how can i bind datepicker js data to angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

i try to bind these 2 following files into my Angular project:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js'></script>
```

creating custom JavaScript file in asset and binding it works fine.

but where can I bind these 2 files? there have no function name and idk how can I call them in the angular component. (I am new @js)

i try to add function name to the files (local saved) but it doesn´t work. what is the right syntax to add a function name to this files?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is simply adding a Bootstrap-style date picker in your Angular project, you might be better off using an Angular native component like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Datepicker demo: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: thank you for your answer. I need a Datepicker in German. and the datepicker i found save the date following for example: Montag, 01.01.2022. I need the weekday in the database for a appointment system.

Comment: If you want to *display* the date in German, it's supported: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#i18n. If you want to *save* the date in German, I think that should rather be a concern of the backend or of the Angular service you use for sending the data to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you want to add any external libraries in Angular always looking it in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) first. Here is a link, hope it'll help you solve your problem, https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-8-bootstrap-4-datepicker-exampleexample.html

Comment: thank you. the problem is the datepicker ist not in german and dont save the weekday